# mySQL query not returning concatenated results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a mySQL query that works in mySQL workbench 5.2, but unfortunately when I translate it over to my php file the CONCAT function is only able to grab FirstName, but not LastName. I am able to retrieve the full name if I don't use the single quotes to build a space between the first and last name, but when I add the code for the spacing, it only retrieves the first name.

For example if I don't add the spacing between the names and call EmployeeName with this modified portion of the code it works:

```
    SELECT * , concat(FirstName,LastName) as 'EmployeeName'
```

but the output would be BruceWayne

The code below is where CONCAT fails to retrieve LastName when I call EmployeeName

```
      $sql = " 

      SELECT * , concat(FirstName," . "' '" . ",LastName) as 'EmployeeName'
      FROM tblEquipment e
      INNER JOIN tblEmployee em on em.employee_id = a.employee_id
      INNER JOIN tblStatus s on s.Status_id = e.equipment_id
      WHERE e.name = " . "'" . $q . "'" . ";
    ";

         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
          echo "
            <td>
                Equipment ID:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' size='25' disabled value = " . $row['Equipment_ID'] . ">
            </td>

            <td style='padding-left:10px;'>
                Currently Assigned To:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' size='25' disabled value = " . $row['EmployeeName'] . ">
            </td>
           ";
           }
```

Output is only the first name : Bruce. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Wait for all the comments saying to use MySQLi and PDO instead of MySQL, even though they are completely useless.

Comment: why are you closing your double quotes to put single quotes in? :: `FirstName," . "' '" .` -works-> `FirstName, ' ',`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `value=` attributes in the HTML markup are not quoted, and therefore will only accept one word up the the first whitespace. You should both escape and quote the value attributes. Whenever you print variables into HTML markup, you need to escape them via `htmlspecialchars()`.

When printing variables into HTML tag attributes, I recommend using [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) with the `ENT_QUOTES` option to escape both single and double quotes inside the attribute.

```
echo "
        <td>
            Equipment ID:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' size='25' disabled value='" . htmlentities($row['Equipment_ID'], ENT_QUOTES) . "'>
        </td>

        <td style='padding-left:10px;'>
            Currently Assigned To:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' size='25' disabled value='" . htmlentities($row['EmployeeName'], ENT_QUOTES) . "'>
        </td>
       ";
       }
```

Note that there is no need to break the string and concatenate in your `CONCAT()`:

```
" SELECT * , concat(FirstName, ' ',LastName) as 'EmployeeName
```

Likewise in the `WHERE`, the `$q` can be directly interpolated in the double-quoted string. We assume it has been properly escaped via `mysql_real_escape_string()`. In the long run, consider switching to an API supporting prepared statements.  The `mysql_*()` API is facing deprecation in the upcoming PHP 5.5.

```
"WHERE e.name = '$q'";
```

Comment: I tried that initially, but that didn't work which is why I tried to concatenate out. :(

Comment: @rawrPowershell It's an HTML escaping and value quoting issue... See change above.

Comment: This is perfect, I tried using the htmlentities portion of the code and it worked perfectly. I appreciate all the help and tips! Thanks!